# Issues integrating Hudson, Maven

Tags: maven, build, hudson, pom.xml

I am integrating Hudson, independent of any webserver, on Mac System
 I deployed hudson.war using command

```
java -jar hudson-2.2.1.war
```

and then integrated my project with hudson from hudson console.

Input following command in shell script section

```
cp -rf /HomeDirectory/TestProject
```

then build the project by clicking "build now"

but I got following error

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] o.h.m.e.h.MavenExecutionResultHandler - Build failed with exception(s)
[INFO] o.h.m.e.h.MavenExecutionResultHandler - [1] org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-readable POM /Users/abc/.hudson/jobs/testproject/workspace/pom.xml: /Users/abc/.hudson/jobs/testproject/workspace/pom.xml (No such file or directory) @
```

From this log what i understood is it couldn't find pom.xml which is true because I don't find any ".hudson" folder in my system that will contain pom.xml(I assume .hudson folder is created automatically on the time of deployment of hudson.war)

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue???

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: do you have your project in a version control system? subversion or git or something supported by hudson would be good. I don't understand how you added your project into hudson with a copy command. Usually you do this on the web-interface. Did you copy the files to their correct location?

Comment: yes I have SVN.yes I did this with the help of User interface..yes files are correctly coppied

Comment: so what are you using the cp command for? Let hudson check out the project from svn directly (point the url to the /trunk folder, so no path to the pom.xml is required)

Comment: Before I answer, what are your goals/objectives for setting up the Hudson build server?  The way you're using Hudson, without and independent app server, is not unheard of.  But the general use case for implementing a build server is to do continuous testing/continuous integration of code in source control.

Comment: Guys, I have resolved the issue ..Someone gave me wrong location of file .. I searched and found the right path ... Thank u for all ur help ... but here is another problem pls have a look... and suggest any solution .   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645711/how-to-get-jbehave-test-reports-in-hudson